# Can an undeclared pointer in C be auto-assigned to NULL by any chance?

Tags: pointers, struct, types, null, initialization

I want to check if a defined struct has been initialized
So i thaught of using

```
typedef struct
{
    int *isInitialized;
} Thing;

int main()
{
    Thing a;
    //Only if initialized, should always fail now
    if (a.isInitialized == NULL)
    {
        //Code
    }
    //I'm saying a is initialized
    a.isInitialized = NULL;
}
```

Will this work or is there any (even small) chance the pointer will automatically be assigned to NULL when declaring a?

EDIT: 
I know it is not always NULL.
I'm asking if it is ever NULL or will it always be some random not-NULL pointer

Comment: I think an answer to this question can be found here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/1597426/3306402

Answer (score 0):

> Will this work or is there any (even small) chance the pointer will automatically be assigned to NULL when declaring a?

No, you can't do that. There is no guarantee that an uninitialised pointer is always NULL.

Similar to `int`, there is no guarantee that an initialised `int` is 0.

```
int a;
if(a == 0)  // should always be zero
{
   // code
}
else  // a must be initialised? wrong
```

Answer (score 0):

If the pointer variable is declared as local, well, there is a chance that the pointer will have the value identical to `NULL`. The immediate problems are 1) when this occurs is pretty much random and 2) compiler will complain that you are accessing uninitialized variable.

On the other hand, if the pointer is declared as global and uninitialized, it is guaranteed that its content is initialized to zero, which, in almost all practical cases, corresponds to `NULL`.